# Collapse Expand tableRow by clicking on the row

Tags: html, jquery

i have found a jfiddle with collapse/expand the row by clicking on the text:

[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHC5C/)

**Html:**

```
 <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
            <td>Cell 4</td>
            <td><a href="#" id="show_1">Show Extra</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <div id="extra_1" style="display: none;">
                    <br>hidden row
                    <br>hidden row
                    <br>hidden row
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Js**

```
$("a[id^=show_]").click(function(event) {
    $("#extra_" + $(this).attr('id').substr(5)).slideToggle("slow");
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

But now i want to click on the Row to expand and not on the Show Extra.
But i cant figure it out how.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kbcm5fL4/1/ see this fiddle.

```js
  $(function(){    
    
        $("a[id^=show_]").click(function(event) {
          $("#extra_" + $(this).attr('id').substr(5)).slideToggle("slow");
          event.preventDefault();
        })
        $('.row').click(function(){   
          $("#extra_1").slideToggle("slow");
          event.preventDefault();  
        }); 
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
    <tr class="row">
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="show_1">Show Extra</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td colspan="5">
            <div id="extra_1" style="display: none;">
                <br>hidden row
                <br>hidden row
                <br>hidden row
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Damn! Thank you for your fast answer! Thats it!

Comment: Welcome. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote you can upvote also you have enough reputation.  @Silazz1378

Comment: Yes now i can! I earned 10 Reputation. Upvote done! Thanks